# Value of state variable is lost - React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jsx

I want to build a CRUD in React with Laravel and Firebase. Everything is perfect when I'm working with text, but I got trouble when I try to upload an image to Firebase Storage. I can save it but I can't get its URL.

I wrote 2 "console.log". In the first one the URL is there, but the second one (when I try to get the URL from the state variable) doesn't return anything.

```
handleSubmit = event =>{ 
  event.preventDefault();

  const {imagen} = this.state;
  if(imagen!=null){
      const uploadTask = storage.ref(`imagenes/${imagen.name}`).put(imagen);
      uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
        this.setState({progress});
      }, 
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }, 
    () => {
        storage.ref('imagenes').child(imagen.name).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
            this.setState({url});
            console.log(this.state.url); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<SHOW URL (IT'S OK!)
        })
    });
  }

var direccion = null;
const form = event.target;
let data = new FormData(form);
data.append('url', this.state.url);
console.log(this.state.url); //<<<<<<<DOESN'T SHOW URL !! (HERE'S THE TROUBLE)
```

If you want to check the entire file:
https://github.com/AndresVasquezPUCE/project/blob/master/pelicula

I'm not a professional, so please don't be rude :D

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, it won't have changed on next line of code when you `console.log`

Answer (score 2):

> this.setState is asynchronous

If you want to get the updated state value, add a callback and access the new state there like

```
this.setState({ url: 'some url'}, () => {
 conosle.log(this.state.url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. By the time your `console.log(this.state.url); //<<<<<<<DOESN'T SHOW URL !! (HERE'S THE TROUBLE)` the data hasn't been loaded from Firebase yet, and the `then` hasn't been called yet.

Any code that needs the data from Firebase needs to either be inside the `then()` callback (such as `console.log(this.state.url); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<SHOW URL (IT'S OK!)`) or be called from there (such as `this.setState({url})`).